# Why do I get an error when trying to retrieve href values, after doing "select" to put all "a" tags in list? BeautifulSoup Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to retrieve all href values from page and put into a list. Here is code I use, note that soup.select("a") successfully puts all a tags including their hrefs into a list called elems:

```
driver.get(your_new_url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

elems = soup.select("a")
print(elems)
time.sleep(20)

links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]

print(links)

driver.quit()
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "find.py", line 31, in
>   
>       links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]   File "find.py", line 31, in 
>       links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#get_attribute is used if you are working with Selenium object .

links = [elem.get('href') for elem in elems]
```